# drawing type of commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams

I drawn a commutative diagram with this code

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{tikzcd}[arrows]
            \node(P0) at (90:2.6cm){V};
            \node(P1) at (90+72:2.5cm){X} ;
            \node(P2) at (90+2*72:4cm){Y};
            \node(P3) at (90+3*72:4cm){W};
            \node(P4) at (90+4*72:2.5cm){U};
            \node(P5) at (270+5*72:4.6cm){Z};
            
            \arrow[from=P1,to=P0,"f_{1}"']
            \arrow[from=P0,to=P4,"f_{2}"']
            \arrow[from=P1,to=P4,"f_{3}"']
            \arrow[from=P1,to=P3,"f_{4}"]
            \arrow[from=P1,to=P2,"f_{6}"]
            \arrow[from=P4,to=P3,"f_{5}"]
            \arrow[from=P2,to=P5,"f_{7}"]
            \arrow[from=P5,to=P3,"f_{8}"]
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

but this picture is very big and I want sth smaller than this, such that Y and W be nearer to X and U. How could I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to add some vertical space between rows 2 and 3. Almost no explicit lengths are needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& V \arrow[dr,"f_2"] \\
X \arrow[ur,"f_1"] \arrow[rr,"f_3"] \arrow[drr,"f_4"] \arrow[d,"f_6"']
&& U \arrow[d,"f_5"] \\[2em]
Y \arrow[dr,"f_7"'] && W \\
& Z \arrow[ur,"f_8"']
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed some label positions, fix them to your liking. Experiment with the `2em` and shorten it a bit to get a more "hexagon-like” shape.

Answer (score 2):

I like very much...how alternative to the classic `tikz-cd` also `xy` package. I add my MWE with the distance of the rows `@R` of `2.5pc`. Peraphs it could be similar to an hexagon :-) like the code of `@egreg` :-); you can adjiust the hexagon with rows and columns changing the parameters of the dots `\xymatrix@R=...pc@C=....pc.`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix@R=2.5pc{
& V \ar[dr]^{f_2}& \\
X \ar[rr]^{f_3} \ar[ur]^{f_1} \ar[d]_{f_6} \ar[drr]^{f_4} &  & U\ar[d]^{f_5} \\
Y \ar[dr]_{f_7}&  & W\\
& Z \ar[ur]_{f_8}& 
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: You have the straight lines zooming in....It is an optical effect of the output.

[image]